# Find the maximum, minimum, and average values in the array

Tags: c

In my code, the program will not allowed the negative number entered, the program will stop reading, then calculate the maximum value, minimum value and average value.
That is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int age[10] = {0};              // initalized an array
  printf("Please enter ages: \n");  // allow user to enter numbers


  for (int i = 0 ;i < 10; i++) {
    scanf("%d",&age[i]);
    if (age[i] < 0) { // if it is negative number, it is should stop reading
      break;
    }
    else if (age[i] >= 0) {
      continue;
    }
  }
  int maximum = age[0];
  int minimum = age[0];
  float average = 0.0;
  int length = sizeof(age) / sizeof(age[0]);
  for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
    if (maximum < age[j]) {
      maximum = age[j];
    } 
    else if (minimum > age[j]) {
      minimum = age[j];
    }
    average += age[j];
  }

  average = average / length;
  printf("%d\n", maximum);
  printf("%d\n", minimum);
  printf("%.1f\n", average);

  return 0;
}
```

Please enter ages: 5 -1
expected result: max:5;min:5,average:5;

actual result: max:5;min:-1,average: 0.4;

That was a question that I met, the code should not accept any negative value.

Thank you all.
but if I add age[i] = 0; then break;
The average value will equal to 0.5.

Comment: Instead of `break` which just breaks out of the loop, print an error message and stop the program. For example with `return 0;`.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what you are asking here. "the program will not allowed the negative number entered, the program will stop reading" ... "my program will accept a negative number then stop reading". Please clarify which one that is the desired behavior (what the program should do) and which one is the incorrect behavior you are getting instead.

Comment: just setting age[i] = 0; before the break; in the first if would solve the problem I think!

Comment: @MohamadGhaithAlzin Irrelevant – the array is zero-initialised anyway, note the `= { 0 }` after the declaration.

Comment: @Mohamad Ghaith Alzin But the average value will equal to 0.5

Comment: So you want the user to enter n numbers and terminate the input with a negative number. E.g. you enter `1 2 3 -1` and then you want to consider only the 3 numbers `[1, 2, 3]`?. Please confirm and [edit] ans make that clear in the question.

Comment: @ Jabberwocky Exactly

Comment: When you enter a negative number how do you know how many numbers were entered previously? After the input loop, what's the difference between entering `1 2 3 -1` and `1 -1`?

Comment: `else if (age[i] >= 0) { continue; }` can be completely removed, it is superfluous code. (the Yoda comparisons got me `:)`

Comment: Side note: `age < 0` and `age >= 0` are *complementary* – if you have such complementary conditions within two subsequent if else if clauses then if first condition is false second can't be anything else than true any more, so the test `if(condition) { 1 } else if(complement) { 2 } else { 3 }`is useless. Just have `if(condition) { 1 } else { 2 }` – (generalisation, *if* `else { 3 }` exists at all, drop it, it can't be met anyway for the same reason).

Comment: And if within a loop you have a `continue` without anything following it, then drop it – continuing is what happens anyway then... So your loop reduces to simply `for(...) { /* scan */ if(age < 0) { break } }` – though simply breaking might not give you the desired results, see Lundin's comment.

Comment: Side note: You do not check the result of `scanf` – you should to, though. It needs to compare equal to the number of items to be scanned, a single one in your case. If it doesn't then a user provided input that cannot be converted to your variable type (like `"I'm a hamster"` – and you should handle this case appropriately, too.

Comment: Optimisation: `int average = age[0];` – calculate with integrals, that's more efficient than floating point arithmetics, and start right with first value of the array; then you can skip first index in the loop: `for(int j = 1; ...)`. Just make sure you convert the average to float correctly before printing: `printf("%f", (float)average/length);`.

Comment: @XuShuoze Adjust scope of `i` and `for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {` --> `for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {`.

Answer (score 3):

- You don't need an array.
- You don't need both a loop variable and a length.
- It's more appropriate to use `? :` for updating minimum/maximum.
- You don't need two loops
- You need to check the `int` return value of `scanf()`, which indicates the number of items successfully scanned, so it should be `1`.  I'll leave that for you/OP to add (hint: replace `for`-loop by `while`-loop to avoid having to add a separate `length` variable again).

```
    int main(void)
    {
        printf("Please enter ages: \n");

        int minimum = INT_MAX;
        int maximum = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;

        for (count = 0; count < 10; count++)
        {
            int age;
            scanf("%d", &age);

            if (age < 0)
            { 
                break;
            }

            sum += age;

            minimum = (age < minimum) ? age : minimum;
            maximum = (age > maximum) ? age : maximum;
        }

        if (count > 0)
        {
            printf("Min: %d\n", minimum);
            printf("Max: %d\n", maximum);
            printf("Avg: %.1f\n", (float)sum / count);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("You didn't enter (valid) age(s).\n");
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Great answer – *but* you missed the point when *no* valid number has been entered thus `count` yet being 0... I'd add, too, checking the result of `scanf` and add an explanation for why that's necessary.

Comment: @Aconcagua Indeed!  I added a comment to my answer and will leave it to the OP to add that.

Comment: Still missing: `if(count == 0) /*!!!*/ { /* error message */ } else { /* printing the output */ }` – with comment for the rest I'm fine.

Comment: @Aconcagua Indeed again :-)

Comment: There's a very minor detail added at volpoh's anwer: `if(maximum)` **`else`** `if(minimum)` – actually clever, if we do have a new maximum we can't have a minimum any more, so in that case a needless test gets skipped... Would need to drop the ternaries for, though.

Comment: @Aconcagua 'Clever' things like this makes code more difficult to understand.  Meaning matters most!

Comment: Well, would really wonder who wouldn't have understood the original if – sometimes people rather ask for what the ternary means (well, one should *know* the language, sure...). Ternary is mainly nice for its *brevity* (like `std::min` or `std::max` in C++) – and luckily we have optimising compilers that should get rid of the self-assignment...

Comment: @Aconcagua You're right, the original is fine.

Comment: Aside: Consider `(double)`  instead of `float` in `printf("Avg: %.1f\n", (float)sum / count);`.  Quotient gets promoted to `double` anyways as part of a `...` argument.

Comment: This is an excellent example of an _on-line_ algorithm, which doesn't need to store history. One could go to 10 of 1000000 without increasing it's footprint. (The `sum` will probably overflow eventually; see [algorithms for calculating varience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Welford's_online_algorithm).)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is overly complicated and wrong.

You want this:

```
  ...
  int length = 0;    // declare length here and initialize to 0

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(age) / sizeof(age[0]); i++) {
    scanf("%d", &age[i]);

    if (age[i] < 0)  // if it is negative number, it is should stop reading
      break;

    length++;        // one more valid number
  }
  
  // now length contains the number of numbers entered
  // the rest of your code seems correct
```

You also might need to handle the special case where no numbers are entered, e.g: the only thing entered is `-1`. It doesn'make sense to calculate the average or the largest/smallest number when there are no numbers.

Comment: Also, `length` can be used a loop variable [like I did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72212984/1971013).

Comment: Please add a hint that `length == 0` needs to be handled explicitly – and I'd did so, too, for checking the result of `scanf`...

Comment: @Aconcagua checking if `scanf` fails is pretty pointless IMO because using `scanf` for interactive input is pointless anyway, `scanf` is just good enough for student's toy programs.

Comment: In a way, yes, but she/he'll won't do it on sscanf after reading entire lines either (or by input from files)...

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be:

(corrections are written in the commented code)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
  int arraySize = 10;
  int age[arraySize]; //initialize not required
  
  //the number of existing values inside the array (effective length)
  int length = 0;

  printf("Please enter ages: \n");  // allow user to enter numbers

  for(int i=0; i<arraySize; i++){
    scanf("%d",&age[i]);
    
    // if it is negative number, it is should stop reading
    if(age[i]<0){ break; }
    
    //the else-if is not required
    //but, if the compiler goes here,
    //it means that the value is acceptable, so
    length++;
  }

  int maximum = age[0];
  int minimum = age[0];
  float average = 0.0;
   
  for(int j=0; j<length; j++){
    if(maximum<age[j]){ maximum = age[j]; } 
    else if(minimum>age[j]) { minimum = age[j]; }
    average += age[j];
  }

  average = average / length;
  printf("%d\n", maximum);
  printf("%d\n", minimum);
  printf("%.1f\n", average);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Aconcagua The code is already edited. Now the length is calculated in the first loop.

Comment: I'd yet initialise average with age[0] as well, then you can start iterating at index 1, so skipping the needless checks for maximum/minimum at index 0.

Comment: You need to additionally handle the case for `length` being 0 – at best right after the first loop by returning, ideally printing some appropriate error message right before.

Comment: @Aconcagua I think that the initialisation of the average var with age[0] wouldn't be a great idea, but it's just my opinion. On the other hand, the code has to be updated, so it can handle the case length = 0. Thx for those advices. :)

Comment: You left updating minimum and maximum with `age[0]` anyway, so what's the difference for the average? All of aren't valid anyway if no valid input is given at all – and if you catch that in advance (as promised), then `age[0]` *is* valid, so you can use it and skip needlessly checking minimum and maximum for very first index.

Comment: @Aconcagua yea sorry, I misunderstood what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

OP's primary problem is the 2nd loop iterates 10 times and not `i` times (the number of times a non-negative was entered.

---

For fun, let us try a non-floating point solution as it really is an integer problem.

An array to store values is not needed.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  // Keep track of 4 things
  int min = INT_MAX; // Set min to the max int value.
  int max = INT_MIN;
  long long sum = 0; // Use wide type to cope with sum of extreme ages.
  int count = 0;

  #define INPUT_N 10

  printf("Please enter ages: \n");
  
  for (count = 0; count < INPUT_N; count++) {
    int age;
    if (scanf("%d", &age) != 1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Missing numeric input.");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (age < 0) {
      break;
    }

    if (age < min) min = age;
    if (age > max) max = age;
    sum += age;
  }

  if (count == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "No input.");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  printf("Maximum: %d\n", max);
  printf("Minimum: %d\n", min);

  // Could use FP and 
  // printf("Average: %.1f\n", 1.0 *sum / count);
  // But for fun, how about a non-FP approach?
 
  #define SCALE 10
  #define SCALE_LOG 1
  sum *= SCALE; // Scale by 10 since we want 1 decimal place.
  // Perform a rounded divide by `count`
  long long average_scaled = (sum + count/2) / count;
  // Print the whole and fraction parts
  printf("Average: %lld.%.*lld\n", 
      average_scaled / SCALE, SCALE_LOG, average_scaled % SCALE);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you must record how many positive numbers you enter. Then the value of `length` will be correct.

Second, for the second `for` loop, `j` must be smaller than the number of positive ages. Therefore, you won't add negative `age[j]` to `average`.

You can simply modify the second for loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int age[10] = {0};              // initalized an array
  printf("Please enter ages: \n");  // allow user to enter numbers


  int length = 0;

  for (int i = 0 ;i < 10; i++) {
    scanf("%d",&age[i]);
    if (age[i] < 0) { // if it is negative number, it is should stop reading
      break;
    }
    else if (age[i] >= 0) {
      length++;
      continue;
    }
  }
  int maximum = age[0];
  int minimum = age[0];
  float average = 0.0;

for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
    if (maximum < age[j]) {
      maximum = age[j];
    } 
    else if (minimum > age[j]) {
      minimum = age[j];
    }

    if ( age[j] > 0.0 )
    {
      average += age[j];
    }
  }

  average = average / length;
  printf("%d\n", maximum);
  printf("%d\n", minimum);
  printf("%.1f\n", average);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: While, the average value will equal to 0.5.

Comment: The expected result of average value should be 5 here

Comment: And the minimum value also 5

Comment: @XuShuoze, I can get the correct result.

Comment: The maximum value, minimum value and average value should equal to 5

Comment: @XuShuoze, please try the new code.

Comment: I understand and this code is working right now. Thanks. :)

Comment: `if ( age[j] > 0.0 )` – this test is obsolete – adding 0 to a float won't change it and the `if` likely is more expensive than the addition. It would be *definitively* if you built the sum as pure `int`s and only converted to float *afterwards*. Code suffers from the same bad style than the original one in the questions, see my comments there.

Comment: Handling the special case of length being 0 is lacking.